# How excess property check helps?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, duck-typing

For the below code,

```
interface SquareConfig{
    color?: string;
    width?: number;
}

interface Square{
    color: string;
    area: number;
}

function createSquare(config: SquareConfig): Square {

    let newSquare:Square = {color: "white", area: 100};
    if (config.color) {
        newSquare.color = config.color;
    }
    if (config.width) {
        newSquare.area = config.width * config.width;
    }
    return newSquare;
}
```

below argument(`myObj`) inferred as type `any` is allowed to pass as argument by type checker at compile time. JS code use duck typing at runtime.

```
let myObj = {colour: 'red', width: 100};

let mySquare = createSquare(myObj);
```

In second case, below argument(other than`SquareConfig` type) is not allowed to pass by type checker at compile time. As mentioned in handbook: *Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments.*

```
let mySquare = createSquare({colour: 'red', width: 100});
```

What is the purpose of excess property check, in second case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the purpose of excess property check, in second case?

It correctly detects bugs (as shown in this case, the misspelling of `color`) without creating too many false positives.

Because the object isn't aliased anywhere else, TypeScript can be fairly confident that the excess property isn't going to be used for a different purpose in some other part of the code. The same cannot be said of `myObj` - we may be inspecting it only for its `.width` here but then using its `.colour` in some other place.

Comment: It is weird that object literal has excess property check, but not object myObj. Why is that?

Comment: Because the object isn't aliased anywhere else, TypeScript can be fairly confident that the excess property isn't going to be used for a different purpose in some other part of the code. The same cannot be said of myObj - we may be inspecting it only for its .width here but then using its .colour in some other place.

Comment: In case of myObj, you know at compile time that it is of type any, then how would you allow it to be passed to function which accepts SquareConfig type?

Comment: `myObj` is not of type `any`.

Comment: `colour` property in `myObj` makes it  of type `any`. Isn't it?

Comment: No; why would that be the case? It has the inferred type `{ colour: string; width: number }`

Comment: Unless I explicitly mention the type as `any` in  `let myObj: any = {colour: 'red', width: 100};`, TS compiler would consider inferred type as `{ colour: string; width: number }`. Is that correct?