# Does assigning an object value before spreading it change its type?

Tags: typescript

When constructing an object by assigning some properties and spreading the rest from another object, it seems that the type of the spread object varies depending on whether it is first assigned to an intermediatry variable.

For example, [here you'll find a sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-vzj24?file=/index.ts:556-644) where the following works just fine,

```
const render = (): RenderReturn => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  const obj = getQueriesForElement(div);
  return {
    someProp: "foo",
    ...obj
  };
}
```

yet when spreading the function result directly, a type error is generated:

```
const render = (): RenderReturn => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  // Types fail
  return {
    someProp: "foo",
    ...getQueriesForElement(div)
  };
}
```

The `RenderReturn` type definition and sample code are in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-vzj24?file=/index.ts).

Which Typescript feature is causing this behaviour?

Does assigning an object before spreading it change its type?

Comment: You're falling victim to excess-property checks. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144243/14357) provides a reasonable explanation of why one fails and the other succeeds. Simply assigning the failing return value to an intermediate variable and returning that instead will dodge the excess prop check.