# How does `Pick` work in Typescript and when would you use it?

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with Typescript and I am a bit confused by the purpose of `Pick`.

I found that :

```
type AB = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: string,
}

type OnlyB = Pick<AB, 'b'>;

const x = {a:'hello', b:'yo', c:'yes'};

const y: OnlyB = x; /*This assignment is fine.*/
const z: OnlyB = {a: 'hello', b:'yo', c:'yes'}; /*This will throw an error */
```

Why is it assigning `x` into `y` is acceptable, but assigning the object straight into `z` is NOT acceptable?

And what does the `Pick` type actually do? Does `y` still hold the entire object with `a`, `b`, and `c` in it, but only `b` is accessible? Or is `y` now just `{b:'yo'}`?

Also, when and why would you actually use `Pick`?

Comment: This isn't related to `Pick` at all, you're seeing [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) behaviour. `a: { x : any } = somethingWithXAndOtherKeys` works but `b: { x: any } = { x:1, y:2 }` doesn't because the latter is directly assigned, while the former is first assigned to a different variable. See also [How excess property check helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50143250)

Answer (score 0):

As VLAZ said, `z` causes a compiler error due to [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). This is because the object literal `{a: 'hello', b:'yo', c:'yes'}` has the extra properties `a` and `c` that are not in `OnlyB`. Having these extra properties is most likely a programming error because you cannot access these properties as `z` has the type `OnlyB`.

> And what does the `Pick` type actually do?

This is the definition of `Pick`:

```
/**
 * From T, pick a set of properties whose keys are in the union K
 */
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

This ‘picks’ certain keys from a type, so that only those properties are present. In your example, `y` has the type `OnlyB`, which is `{b: string}`, so this will cause errors:

```
// Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Pick<AB, "b">'.
y.a
// Property 'c' does not exist on type 'Pick<AB, "b">'.
y.c
```

However, `y` will still have the `a` and `c` properties at runtime.