# Subset shape-matching of Typescript doesnt work properly

Tags: typescript

As you know one of the TypeScript’s core principles is that type checking focuses on the shape that values have, this is sometimes called **duck typing** or **structural typing**. Also the shape-matching only requires a subset of the object’s fields to match.

For example, following code is totally acceptable for Typescript:

```
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

function logPoint(p: Point) {
  console.log(`${p.x}, ${p.y}`);
}

const rect = { x: 33, y: 3, width: 30, height: 80 };
logPoint(rect); // logs "33, 3"
```

But if you call **logPoint** function directly with object literal, Typescript will warn you:

```
logPoint({ x: 33, y: 3, width: 30, height: 80 }); // error
```

So, what is the difference? Why subset type-mathcing works in first case and doesnt in second one?

Links:

[Structural type system reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system)

[First example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRmQbwFDLIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANwHICeZltDeAvnnjBSARhg6EMgA26AOYYsACgAOZWeACUuJglEBndOIgA6SVLkADACQ4FBolwA0yS9eZdTqxjzxaQ27FAhCyAC8uMRkAMzhDqzIUcgA7sAAJmAAFhEADA6pEMBSqWBkABwZyFyMeMYqYHL+Qu7IAPSNEtLayABEkQ7hHUA)

[Second example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRmQbwFDLIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANwHICeZltDeAvnnjBSARhg6EMgA26AOYYsACgAOZWeACUuJglEBndOIgA6SVLkADACQ4FBolwA0yS9eZdTqxjzzGVYOTmJkAMyBDqzIIcgA7sAAJmAAFkEADA7xEMBS8WBkABxJyFzuyAD0xcjQUOhQQA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How excess property check helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143250/how-excess-property-check-helps)

Comment: I am not sure why it's like that. But while you might be doing something productive with your `rect` object, there is simply no practical reason to use a literal argument that's not an exact type match. So, I'd guess, either TS is trying to protect you from an obvious mistake, or the TS developers didn't want to do the work to support a useless use case.

Answer (score 0):

It's because typescript has two levels of strictness, depending on what you're trying to do.

When *creating* an explicitly-typed object, typescript does the strictest interpretation and does not all you to add any extra properties. Your second example is a case of this: In the context you're creating this object literal, the only possible type it could have is `Point`, but you're giving it extra properties and so typescript points out this is probably a mistake.

Another example of the stricter checking would be the following. I've explicitly said i'm creating a Point, but it's got extra stuff:

```
const rect: Point = { x: 33, y: 3, width: 30, height: 80 };
```

Your first example on the other hand doesn't get this extra strictness. The line of code that creates the object doesn't specify a type, so typescript automatically gives it the type `{ x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number }`. Then later you pass this object into the function. Unlike when you create an object with a specific type, this case has typescript just compare whether the types are "compatible", and extra properties don't hurt that.

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe is right

It is called: [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error:

If you still want to use reference, there is a workaround:

```js
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

type IsPoint<T> = T extends Point ? Point extends T ? T : never : never;

function logPoint<T>(p: IsPoint<T>) {
  console.log(`${p.x}, ${p.y}`);
}

const rect = { x: 33, y: 3, width: 30, height: 80 };
const rect2 = { x: 33, y: 3};

logPoint(rect); // error, because Point does not extends width and height props

logPoint(rect2) // ok 

logPoint({ x: 33, y: 3, width: 30, height: 80 }); // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRmQbwFDLIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANwHICeZltDeAvnnmMwAcUASQDOGLAB4AKgD5kAXmTTkEIpBAATUWkzhkAfl1ZV6iFp0qjKthABu0ZLYdRGeGBRAIwwdCGQANugA5hLgMrIAFAJkYmFgEQCUuEwIfqLoARAAdEHBkQAGACQ4AtlEXAA0yCVlzFwFiYw8eGkgothQEN6KuMRkAMwD1azIw8gA7sCaYAAWgwAM1bMQwMGzYGQAHAvIXIxtHchd3gBMvTj9Y%20OjA-u8efGRJ2BNyAD076pQUOhQeI89GBnt0wKdkp9kOgANbIAEhJ6XUjXEaDapTGbzMZLZArNYbba7LhvSHQX7-IA)