# React Component Exact TypeScript Prop Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-props, react-typescript

When I have this:

```
interface PropTypes {
   user?: {
      name?: string,
      age?: number
   }
}
const Comp = (props: PropTypes) => ...
```

Why this works:

```
const user = {
   random: 3,
   name: 'test'
}
<Comp user={user} />  // works
```

But this does not (moved value from variable to here):

```
<Comp user={{ random: 3,  name: 'test' }} />   // does not work
```

Also when I delete all known properties from user it does not work anymore:

```
const user = {
   random: 3
}
<Comp user={user} />   // does not work
```

I want to know why it works like this. Why it accepts the "random" prop, that is unknown for him when it is in variable. Why variable type has different behaviour than directly passing prop? Is there any way to allow only exact props without giving type each time to the variable?

Comment: Because excess property checks aren't applied everywhere. You could re-use user, but the literal is _only_ passed as a prop. Why don't you define a User type to use in both places?

Comment: Looking for a simpler solution. In JS they lead to same result, It is strange that it works like this in TS.

Comment: Lots of things work in JS that TS doesn't allow, that's its purpose. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50143250/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with Typescript's **Excess Property Checking**.

> Structural Type System: TypeScript is fine with having extra properties as long as you provide a type with its’ required properties.

> When TypeScript encounters object literal in assignments or when passed as an argument to functions it triggers an action called **Excess Property Checking**. Contrary to structural typing, it check whether the object has the exact properties.

> One interesting behavior is with “**Weak Types**” — types which all their fields are marked as Optional. In this case the excess property checking an action takes place even when assigning intermediate variable.

You can read more at [this link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/typescript-excess-property-checks-6ffe5584f450).

### Case 1 - Structural Type System

```
const user = {
   random: 3,
   name: 'test'
}
<Comp user={user} />  // works
```

In this case the type of `user` is inferred as:

```
{
  random: number;
  name: string;
}
```

This type is compatible with `PropTypes`, so no error.

### Case 2 - Excess Property Checking

Passing object literal in assignments:

```
<Comp user={{ random: 3,  name: 'test' }} />   // does not work
```

In this case `random` is not a valid property for type `PropTypes`, so typescript tells you adding `random` is an error.

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'random' does not exist in type '{ name?: string | undefined; age?: number | undefined; }'

### Case 3 - Weak Types

```
const user = {
   random: 3
}
<Comp user={user} />   // does not work
```

In this case typescript inferred the type of user as:

```
{
  random: number;
}
```

Also in this case `random` is an invalid property for `PropTypes`, so this is an error.

Comment: Why case 2 is different than case 1. They both have same values. In first case the type of user is: {
  random: number;
  name: string;
} and there are no errors while passing it to component. In second case the type is exactly the same as the first. Why there is an error in case 2? Type {
  random: number;
  name: string;
} can cast to typeof user in first case, but in second is same, why it can not cast there? ...

Comment: It is because of Excess Property Checking, I expanded the answer to cover this topic

Comment: What's the difference between  name: string and name: string | null